C# ProjectId causing warning in project references
I have noticed in one of my Visual Studio solutions that the PackageId attribute in the .csproj file are causing yellow warnings when the project is referenced in another one.

If I remove PackageId from the .csproj file, it seems that no warning is shown.
I have seen that this is happening when project reference directory is using $(SolutionDir) in csproj.
Note: I'm using $(SolutionDir) in project references directory because sometimes I'm using submodules in Git.
I have reproduced the issue in a small solution.

Create empty solution
Inside SolutionDir add folder named Submodule (also I have added Submodule solution folder).
Create ProjectA in Submodule folder.
Create ProjectB in solution folder.

ProjectA with Nlog nugget added for example.
ProjectB referencing ProjectA using $(SolutionDir).
With this solution I can see ProjectA with warning in reference list of ProjectB. If I comment PackageId line in ProjectA warning disappears.
ProjectA.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 
    <PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
<Title>Console Infra</Title>
<Version>2.0.491</Version>
<Company>Company</Company>
<Copyright>Copyright © Company 2020</Copyright>
<AssemblyVersion>2.0.491</AssemblyVersion>
<Authors>Author</Authors>
<Product>Console Infra</Product>
<PackageId>Console Infra</PackageId>
</PropertyGroup>
 
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.8" />
</ItemGroup>
 
</Project>

ProjectB.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 
    <PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
<Title>Console Module</Title>
<Version>2.0.217</Version>
<Company>Company</Company>
<Copyright>Copyright © Company 2020</Copyright>
<AssemblyVersion>2.0.217</AssemblyVersion>
<Authors>Sedecal</Authors>
<Product>Console Module</Product>
<PackageId>Console Module</PackageId>
</PropertyGroup>
 
  <ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="$(SolutionDir)\Submodule\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
 
</Project>


What do I need to do to reproduce your issue?

My solution is very big but I have noticed this behaviour. I can try to give some example

@Wyck I have reproduced the issue in small solution. I have edited the question.

Hi,@JuanDYB. Could you share a screenshot of your warning? The warning still exists when I comment the ProjectID line in ProjectA.  Since TargetFramework is netstandard2.0, I use ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 for testing.

Hi @HuiLiu-MSFT, I have added screenshot of warning.

Hi,@JuanDYB. I open the project without Console Infra and today there is no warning icon. I added Console Infra in .csproj and rebuilt both projects, but I don't see the warning icon either. What version of your Visual Studio is it? Mine is Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - current version 17.9.2.

[![enter image description here][1]] [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/2h7Jc.png

Hi @HuiLiu-MSFT I'm using Visual Studio 2022. Try to restart visual studio and reopen project with PackageId set. In my case shows warning.

Maybe there are some details that affect it. Maybe there are some details that affect it. Have you tried removing Console Infra and unloading the project and closing Visual Studio, then reopening Visual Studio and reloading the project and adding Console Infra to rebuild to see the results?

Yes, I have tried to restart visual studio with and withput PackageId, it seems that only fails with PackageId.

Well, I'll keep looking for possible causes and will come back if there are updates. If you find a solution, please feel free to share it.

Hi @HuiLiu-MSFT My thanks so much for your reply! I have posted becase I thought that it was strange and I didn't understand what is the relation between PackageId and the warning

It is likely related to the way Visual Studio resolves project references and handles the PackageId attribute in the referenced project's .csproj file. You could try to use the NoWarn property like below:



1.Ensure that the PackageId attribute in all projects is unique and follows a consistent naming convention.2.Ensure that the paths to the referenced projects are correct and consistent. using $(SolutionDir) in project reference paths can sometimes lead to unexpected behavior, especially if the solution directory structure changes or if you're working with submodules in Git. Consider using relative paths or other methods to reference projects within the same solution.3.Check if there are any circular dependencies or conflicting dependencies between projects in your solution.
